# How to extract only email addresses from text file. I'm trying to use Dreamweaver

Tags: html, search, replace, adobe, dreamweaver

How to extract only email addresses from text file.  I'm trying to do it in Dreamweaver (Search and Replace)…… however, I’m open to other solutions.

The email addresses will need to be saved to a text file; one email address per line.

Thanks

The Text file looks like this:

jon.park@CALPERS.CA.GOV                               anne.hollinhead@LAO.CA.GOV                                    karn.whites.COMMUNITYSOLUTIONS.ORG                                  dperkins@CITYOFAVENAL.COM                           marykathryn.clay@DHCS.CA.GOV                    charlene.manning@CALHR.CA.GOV
arivera@HFH-CONSULTANTS.COM Andy River 488-390-8293                           kristi.biwn@SEN.CA.GOV Kristina Brn/916-631-1769                           andy.diff@DOF.CA.GOV Andy Diff                                            Liren.goadian@GMAIL.COM Liren goadian                                         joenfly@KERN.ORG Jay Fly /; 661-684-4215                                jmcark@CI.OCEANSIDE.CA.US Jay Mark / 763-495-5832                       tytgomez@CI.OCEANSIDE.CA.US Tera Gomez/ 769-435-5818                           rdxteming@BEAUMONTCARES.COM Rebe Ddorming 657-577-3255                           vgytierorz@SCO.CA.GOV Vilma G/916.319.8550                           timmyriverlin@OCFA.ORG Timmera Riverline                                               dcurdoch@M-W-H.COM dclex Milant (918) 445-3902                                  kavinm.listw@EMSA.CA.GOV Kavinm Lists  918-431-3745

I tried different expressions in Dreamweaver that let me only see part of the email addresses; however, I cannot save only the email address as a list/other.

I use this expression in Search and Replace to find the email address: (\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)|

How do I copy/export the results to a HTML or Txt file?

Comment: Are you creating the text file yourself, or are you receiving the text file the way it is and having to compromise with it?

Comment: your regex is incorrect, it should be `(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)` (note the escaped dot in the domain)

Comment: If you don't mind switching editor, In [VSCode](https://vscode.dev/) (there is desktop version too) you can search with the regex (`CTRL`+`F` then click on `.*` icon) and then hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`L` to highlight all found strings and copy/paste it into a new document.